# Bluetooth Keyboards

Tags: ps3, keyboard

Are there any worthwhile alternatives to the official PS3 wireless keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the official PS3 wireless keyboard, every other keyboard I have investigated appears to lack **full** support for PS3 specific buttons (R1, R2, L1, L2, Triange, Circle, Square, Cross, Select, Start, PS).

The best of the bunch in my opinion is the [Logitech DiNovo Mini](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/keyboards/keyboard/devices/3848) keyboard. It isn't cheap but is beautifully made, has cool LEDs, great battery life and the keyboard/trackpad is excellent. Although not designed specifically for the PS3, it does have a PS3 switch that remaps some of the keys to be PS3 orientated. (i.e. Cross = Enter, Circle = Esc, Triangle = Fn + OK, PS button = MS logo etc).

Once the keyboard has been paired with the PS3 it works instantly. If I want to type something, I flip up the lid of the DiNovo and just start typing.

Answer (score 0):

Again not specifically for the PS3, but I am using the [CHINFAI Silicone wireless keyboard](http://www.google.com/search?q=CHINFAI%20Silicone%20Wireless%20Keyboard).

A little bit hard to type upon, but after you get used to its wobbly keys, its main feature is that it can be rolled up and stored inside your travel bag if you carry your PS3 to your friends and need your tools with you.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Logitech MediaBoard Pro. It works great as a normal keyboard/mouse for a PC, and works ok for the PS3.

I wouldn't recommend it as keyboard to play games (like UT3), but for normal keyboard/mouse interaction it works well.

Answer (score 0):

The PS3 has standard USB ports on the front panel. I've used a USB (but otherwise standard) PC/Mac keyboard several times. If you're chatting in PlayStation Home, entering password or profile information, or pretty much anything else that requires much typing, it's a quick and usable solution.